# Execute a function after a thread finishes executing

Tags: python, pyqt

So I have a program which a runs a Qt GUI. I don't want to post code of my program but the code I'm showing is applicable to mine. So I got my file with a new thread.

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    print("Starting Thread")
    time.sleep(5)
    some_method()
    some_method2()
    print("Closing Thread")
```

And i got my main.py

```
from threadFile import MyThread
t1 = MyThread()
MyThread.start()
self.some_other_method()
```

I want that *some_other_method()* to run after the *t1* Thread is done. I can't use *.join()* because it freezes the UI and I cant include *some_other_method()* in the *threadFile* because *some_other_method(*) is an instance method in my main.py and importing the class in my *threadFile* would produce a circular import. I hope my problem is clear.

Comment: Okay first that is not how you implement a Thread in PyQt (or Qt in general) and you should not mix python threads with Qt that is what the QThread is for.  Next before you go there -- when properly using a QThread you do not sub-class it but instead you use the moveToThread function and lastly to avoid freezing when implementing a continuous loop you must use QCoreApplication.processEvents function.  That should give you enough to dig into the details and figure out how to implement this.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answere didn't know about QThread. Going to have a look at it as soon as possible.

Comment: there is also `QTimer.singleShot` if you want to run a function/method after a certain time.

Answer (score 1):

Then create a QObject that emits the finished signal when the tasks are finished executing, and through that signal invoke the function you want:

```py
import threading
import time

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Signaller(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.signaller = Signaller()

    def run(self):
        self.signaller.started.emit()
        print("Starting Thread")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Closing Thread")
        self.signaller.finished.emit()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Press me")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_clicked(self):
        self.button.setEnabled(False)
        t1 = MyThread()
        t1.signaller.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        t1.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_finished(self):
        self.some_other_method()
        self.button.setEnabled(True)

    def some_other_method(self):
        print("test")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```